# How to find mean of successive entries in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have a dataframe which has numerical values similar to this :

df

```
probability
0
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
```

I need to find the mean of the probabilities for each successive entries and want the following

expectedMeanDF

```
mean
0
0.1
0.25
0.35
0.45
1
```

where 0.1 is the mean of 0 and 0.2, 0.25 for 0.2 and 0.3 and so on...

I'm using window functions in the following way to do this :

```scala
df.withColumn("partition", dp.col("probability")*0)

val window = Window.partitionBy("partition")
val mean = distinctProbability.withColumn("mean", (newdp.col("probability") + lead("probability", 1).over(window)) / 2).drop("partition").drop("probability")
```

So I have two problems with this approach :

1. It's not able to append 0 and 1 at first and last positions of the dataframe respectively
2. It's not very efficient. The number of rows in my df might go upto 30 million so that is a challenge.

Any alternate approach for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

30 million is not a large number so a local processing could be fast enough but it is not correct. `partitionBy` causes a shuffle and without `orderBy` data can be put in a different order than you expect.

The only scalable solution I know is to convert to RDD:

```
val df = Seq(0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5).toDF("probability")
val rdd = df.orderBy($"probability").as[Double].rdd
```

import `RDDFunctions`

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions._
```

use sliding method:

```
val slides = rdd.sliding(2).toDS
```

find mean:

```
val means = slides.map(slide => slide.sum / slide.size)
```

and convert back to `DataFrame`:

```
means.toDF
```

It will cover all consecutive values:

```
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|  0.1|
| 0.25|
| 0.35|
| 0.45|
+-----+
```

but you'll have to add range boundaries manually.